# Access a value from a list field in django

Tags: django, django-mongodb-engine

I have a list field in my django model for users as follows:
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField() 
    profiles = ListField()

I am using mongo as storage database with help of django_mongodb_engine.
For one user, model object could be like

```
 {name: 'Alice', email: 'abc', profiles: ['Read']}
```

For another user it could be:

```
 {name: 'John', email: 'xyz', profiles: ['Read', 'Write']}
```

I want to search for users which are assigned Read profile to them.
In mongo db shell it can be performed simply by adding in query

```
{'profiles': 'Read'}
```

. 
Can we perform search like that via django querysets ? When I tried, it gave me an exception "list indices must be integers, not str". Please guide me in this regards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution may be using raw queries with help of `MongoDBManager`:

```
from django_mongodb_engine.contrib import MongoDBManager

class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()
    profiles = ListField()

    objects = MongoDBManager()
```

and then:

```
UserModel.objects.raw_query({'profiles': 'Read'})
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look again to understand problem better. Thanks.